# Can I use Vim editing mode on the command line without losing recursive history search?

Tags: vim, history, zsh

I'm uzing zsh and, because I'm an avid Vim user, I just switched to using Vim-style editing on the command line. (That means if I type `ls foo/bar` and decide I want to `cd` instead, I can hit `Esc ^` to hop back to the beginning and `cw cd` to change `ls` to `cd`.

That's all dandy, but the problem is that I can no longer use `Ctrl+R` to do recursive history search. Is there another way to do it, or can I somehow override the Vim keybinding to get it back?

Comment: A hard choice! `garyjohn` shows a Vim way to do it, and `JdeBP` shows how to get the keybinding for Ctrl+R back! I'm going to play with both methods and accept an answer later. I'll decide based on 1) which method seems easier to me and 2) which gets more upvotes. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course you can no longer use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.  If you consult the Z Shell manual you'll see that there's only a key binding for the `history-incremental-search-backward` widget in the `emacs` keymap.  There are no key bindings for it in the vi keymaps.

But as you'll also find from reading the manual (It's chapter 18.), adding a key binding is a fairly simple exercise in the use of the `bindkey` command:

```
bindkey "^R" history-incremental-search-backward
```

You don't even have to use the `zle` command to map the widget onto a shell function, since this is a standard widget.

If you consult [the answer to this same question that is on the Z Shell wiki](http://zshwiki.org./home/zle/bindkeys#why_isn_t_control-r_working_anymore), you'll see the commands for specifically adding this to the vi "command" and "insert mode" keymaps:

```
bindkey -M viins '^R' history-incremental-search-backward
bindkey -M vicmd '^R' history-incremental-search-backward
```

Also note that, [as garyjohn points out](https://superuser.com/questions/328026#328044), in the vi "command" keymap, the <kbd>/</kbd> character is bound to the `vi-history-search-backward` widget.  The difference between this widget and the `history-incremental-search-backward` widget is the widget behaviour that applies *once one is in* history search mode.  Here are a couple of the differences that you will notice:

- Switching vi modes:

  - The search mode in `history-incremental-search-backward` toggles between the `main` and `vicmd` keymaps when you invoke the `vi-cmd-mode` widget whilst still staying in search mode.  i.e. from `emacs` mode presssing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> keys toggles the search mode between the `emacs` and `vicmd` keymaps.  (Invoking `history-incremental-search-backward` from the `vicmd` keymap is thus troublesome, unless you bind something to `vi-cmd-mode` in the `vicmd` keymap as well.)
  - The search mode in `vi-history-search-backward` treats the `vi-cmd-mode` widget as `accept-line` and will end the search, re-entering the command mode that you entered the search from.  i.e. (with the default bindings) <kbd>/</kbd> enters search mode from command mode and <kbd>Esc</kbd> goes back to command mode.
- Repeating a search:

  - In `history-incremental-search-backward`, both the `history-incremental-search-backward` and the `vi-rev-repeat-search` widgets are recognized.  i.e. (presuming that you have altered the bindings as above) both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>N</kbd> will search for a preceding matching line.
  - In `vi-history-search-backward`, only the `vi-rev-repeat-search` widget is recognized.  i.e. (presuming that you have altered the bindings as above) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> will cause a beep and be ignored.

Comment: My muscle memory blesses you!

Answer (score 4):

In bash's vi mode, typing `<Esc>/<string><Enter>` will search the command history for `<string>`. `n` will search further back in history; `N` will search forward. zshell may be the same.

Comment: That's interesting, though - I frequently use search as a movement in Vim. I guess I can't use it to move within the command I'm currently editing, since it's pegged to searching history, eh?

Comment: Right. But you can (at least in bash) use the f, F, t, T, ';' (semicolon), and ',' (comma) commands to move forward and back to particular characters in the line.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use:

```
bindkey -M vicmd '/' history-incremental-search-backward
```

This way I can type `ESC /text` and see the command line. If I want to go the next match I type `ESC n`